# Android - change default Language of Date Picker

Tags: android, datetimepicker, android-calendar

I have a calendar that is in English. For Example, Days and Months {Sunday, Monday, ....., Saturday} , Month {January, ....., December}. Is it possible to change the content without adding any dependencies?

I have used as a test the Date Picker in this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm), but cannot change the content inside((.

Here is my code:

```
      _imgDoB.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == _imgDoB) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                _edtxDOB.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
   <RelativeLayout ...........

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtx_DoB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/tug_kun"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_gender"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:maxLength="10"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img_DoB"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edtx_DoB"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_gender"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/raqam_kiriting"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What kind of content do you want to change ?

Comment: Want to change english language into russian. i know how it is done with github, since there is ready library. but i want to have my own custom date time picker